# Содержимое переменной (запроса к SQL) в отдельном файле

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

Вероятно вопрос глупый, но мне хочется разобраться.
В Pandas создаю подключение к MSSQL с последующим сохранением данных в DataFrame.

[image: Подключение к MSSQL]

Код у меня работает исправно, но вид не нравится. Мне хочется минимизировать данные в открытой книге, а работать только с полученными данными после запроса. Длина myQuery в 2 высоты экрана, что просто бесит:-)

Тут и возникла необходимость спрятать большой запрос к SQL в файл и подгрузить его как переменную в книге. Как мне это сделать?

Нужно так:
myQuerry = Путь\файл, что-то ещё.

Предположу, что в Pandas это как-то надо делать минуя питоновский "with open"

Comment: создайте файл `common.py` в той же папке что и основной скрипт, засуньте в него `myQuery` и в текущем коде: `from common import myQuery`. И не нужно будет никаких `open` использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдержка из [онлайн документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html):

```
pandas.read_sql(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None,
                parse_dates=None, columns=None, chunksize=None)
```

> **sql** : string or SQLAlchemy Selectable (select or text object)
>   SQL query to be executed or a table name.

Т.е. указать просто имя файла не получится, но можно минимизировать код, воспользовавшись модулем `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

sql_fn = '/path/to/sql_file.sql'

df = pd.read_sql(Path(sql_fn).read_text(), engine)
```